# Installing Apple HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to know how to install the Apple's HTTP Live Streaming tools on my webserver. Since the tools provided by Apple is in dmg format. I have tested the tools on my local MAC machine. Also I encoded the live streams and VOD's using FFMpeg Library on MAC.

Since streaming videos require webserver for distributing content, how we install both these tools on webserver both FFMpeg and Live Streaming Tools by Apple?

I guess it might be very silly question, but couldn't get a workaround on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you tested on your Mac, you already know how to install them. Do the same on the server. But I'm guessing your server is not a Mac ( you need to put that in your question)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But do we need OS X server to be installed? 
Won't Linux or Windows server help.

Comment: Because the apple tools (mediafilesegmenter, etc) are not available on Windows/linux.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I need to purchase OS X Server (https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/os-x-server/id883878097?mt=12) and then install ffmpeg and apple tools on that.

How do I make it automated? For e.g. If a live stream feed is coming from a camera the ffmpeg will convert the video into ts files and then it should be passed to Apple HTTP Live Streaming tools to get desired output. 

Source could be a live feed or VOD.

Comment: I found that OS X server is free, if you have Apple developer account. But my question is how I make the process automated on server. Any help is appreciated.